# Is there a preference of when to use \text and \mathrm?

Tags: amsmath, best-practices

I'm unsure of when it is preferable to use `\text` versus `\mathrm`, is there some unwritten rule about the use of these?

For example, I saw the following code in a math post:

```
\frac{\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)}{\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)}\quad\text{divides}\quad 
\frac{\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)}{|\langle x\rangle\cap\langle y\rangle|}\quad
\text{divides}\quad \mathrm{ord}(ab)\quad\text{divides}\quad
\mathrm{lcm}(m,n).
```

and there is a mix of both. Is there a general reason why the author would choose to do so?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

*Caution*: the following discussion assumes that the package **amsmath** has been loaded.

In general `\mathrm` should be used for "symbols" and `\text` for, yes, text. :)

However, it's best to use operators for clusters of Roman letters that represent functions: the commands `\lcm` and `\gcd` are predefined; for "ord" there's not a predefined command, but it suffices to put in the preamble

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}
```

(the command's name can be what one wants). The input before would become

```
\frac{\lcm(m,n)}{\gcd(m,n)}
\quad \text{divides} \quad
\frac{\lcm(m,n)}{|\langle x\rangle\cap\langle y\rangle|}
\quad \text{divides} \quad
\ord(ab)
\quad \text{divides} \quad
\lcm(m,n)
```

In this case `\text{divides}` and `\mathrm{divides}` might give the same result, but they are conceptually different (and can actually be printed in different ways, depending on the math fonts used). Spaces in the argument of `\mathrm` are ignored, for example. Moreover, `\text` honors the font of the surrounding environment: it will print in italics in the statement of a theorem.

Particular attention should be paid to units such as "m/s"; it's best not to do them "by hand", but employ a package like **siunitx** that takes care of all the subtleties, while being very flexible.

Comment: i suggest also putting any surrounding spaces within the scope of `\text{ ... }` -- it's easier to see that they're present when you do that.

Comment: `\text{divides}` and `\mathrm{divides}` are not always the same. Using `unicode-math` with OpenType math fonts, the math alphabets come from the math font instead of the text fonts, by default. Anyway, it is a good answer and I voted it up -:)

Comment: @Yan: that's a good comment, that shows more differences between the two commands.

Comment: Maybe you’d like to mention `siunitx` in your answer to typeset numbers and/or units as a third kind of text (operators, units, text). Which are also often set with `\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}` instead of `\si{\meter\per\second}`, which I prefer becuase it’s more flexible and able to be changed globally.

Comment: Furthermore, I prefer `\text{ divides }` to `\quad \text{divides} \quad`. The former gives it a more "text-like" spacing.

Comment: Another issue of `\mathrm` is, that you "can't" use accentes, like umlauts (in principle, you can, but you will get warnings about `…is invalid in math-mode`)

Comment: I have been thinking for some time about the best practices wen it comes to notations like Aut(G), Hom(V,W), Matₙ(ℂ) etc. Mathematically, they are not really “operators”, so should I use `\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}` or `\newcommand\Aut{\mathrm{Aut}}`?

Comment: @Gaussler They *are* operators just like “log” and “sin”.

Comment: @egreg As mentioned, I agree on the LaTeX side, but not on the mathematical side. How about the identity map when denoted by upright “id”? Operator or `\mathrm`?

Comment: @Gaussler It's debatable for the identity map, for technical reasons, because it's usually used by itself. But I see no problem with "Hom” or “Aut”, just like “ker”.

Comment: If one uses `unicode-math` is `\symup` acceptable for math mode text, as in text sub/superscripts?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL No: you want, say, “eff” (for “efficient”) to have the ligature.

Comment: So are units considered "symbols" that should use `mathrm` instead of `text`?  (Assuming units packages aren't available)

Comment: @endolith Yes, they’re symbols.

Comment: Define "symbols" here. Is this in a programmatic sense, as in a variable name, or in a typographical sense, as in special characters?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs In mathematical sense

Comment: @egreg Define `mathematical sense`.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Why should I? Have I got any obligation towards you? You're being rude, do you know? Ask the BIPM, which says that the units are *symbols*. You know, mathematics, not programming.

Comment: @egreg I apologise if I come off as rude. But I really don't understand what was meant by `Symbols` here.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs
 To egreg: Just that you know: viewing from the sidewalk, you seem as being a bit *more rude* than SBRBL.  This is in addition *to being wrong*…  (First, BIPM has zero authority in a mathematical context.  Second, ME authoritatively shows that SI units are not symbols “in mathematical sense” — this is the M.Shubin’s article in т.4,кол.1133–1135.)  Probably you mean that they behave as “special characters in an alphabet” — as Chinese tried to do in Chinese computer encodings (so now we are forced to live with the corresponding “compatibility characters” of Unicode…).

Comment: @IlyaZakharevich So, you decide who's authoritative? Maybe I'm wrong according to Shubin, but I'm not according to BIPM, which is *the* authority in this field.

Comment: Hmm?!  Can you point out at least *one* confirmation that BIMP is an authority on what is the meaning of the word “symbol” **in mathematics**?  And: it is not me: it is the editors of the Mathematical Encyclopedia who decided on who's authoritative…

Answer (score 24):

You should use `\text` if you are writing *text* (i.e. not math, but words) and `\mathrm` if you are writing *math*, but with Roman letters.  In fact, `\mathrm` is of extremely limited utility because of the feature egreg described: the `\DeclareMathOperator` command, which covers 99% of the cases where non-variable letters appear in math (namely, as operators like `lcm` or `gcd`).

In fact, the code you are asking about is really quite bad, being overly wordy and careless about what the markup denotes.  In addition to egreg's improvements, I'd advocate doing something like

```
\newcommand{\genby}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}
\newcommand{\card}[1]{\lvert #1\rvert}
```

and replacing the second quantity with

```
\frac{\lcm(m,n)}{\card{\genby{x} \cap \genby{y} } }
```

I mention this although it does not concern `\mathrm` because it is a symptom of the problem afflicting the entire sample: one must *infer* the author's intent in constructing the *output* to have a particular *appearance* rather than be told unambiguously by the way they wrote the *input* to have a particular *meaning*.  The use of `\mathrm` is the most widespread manifestation of this issue.

The result is that the author is making it harder on themselves, in the end, by forcing their mind to envision this piece of mathematics not as math but as the collection of its constituent symbols.  Consequently, it is slower to construct, lengthier to type, and also more prone to irritating inconsistencies when they forget their own conventions later.

Comment: The [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package has an equivalent of `\DeclareMathOperator` but for delimiters, `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` which allows a greater control over the size of the delimiters. Your examples would become `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\genby}{\langle}{\rangle}` `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\card}{\lvert}{\rvert}`.

Comment: @Philippe: very nice!

Answer (score 11):

If you aren't going to be using the operator often and don't want to use `\DeclareMathOperator` in the preamble, you can use `\operatorname` instead. [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Custom_operators) is some documentation in the Wikibook.

Comment: In particular, this works with MathJax (which I mention because you said you saw the code "in a math post").

Answer (score 9):

I do not use `\mathrm` very much, but I do tend to use it for differentiable operators such as `dx` or `dy` or `dz`, `\ldots` etc.

Something like this.

```
\[ \int_0^{\pi} \! \sin(t)~\mathrm{d}t \]
```

it makes the `d` not a italicized letter when used in math mode.  Hope that is a little helper of which one could use it for. I still want to find out more of it uses.

Comment: You can use a pair of backticks ` to enclose your inline codes. For displayed codes, highlight your codes and press the 1010 button.

Comment: @xport: Thanks for the insight. Will try to incorporate these things on a regular.

Comment: for the differential, a thin space `\,` is preferable to `~`

Comment: Also using `sin` instead of `\sin` is a sin. :-)

Comment: @celtschk: Thanks for catching that, must of overlooked. Fixed now. `:)`

Comment: On a related note: I used `\text{}` for defining a differential operator command and getting straight `d`s. The problem was that, within a `theorem` environment, the behaviour would get overridden and I would get an italicized d. Using `\mathrm{}` instead of `\text{}` (or `\textrm{}`) to define my differential command solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\operatorname{lcm}` results in proper spacing in things like this:

```
a\operatorname{lcm}b
```

The same is true of this:

```
\operatorname{ord}
```