# Difference between \textrm{} and \mathrm{}

Tags: math-mode

Can you explain me what is the difference between `\textrm{}` and `\mathrm{}` when they are used in math mode. In what context one is preferred over the other?

Comment: There's a similar question here, relating to `\text` vs. `\mathrm`. [Is there a preference of when to use \text and \mathrm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19502/2693).

Comment: The one is using text fonts and the other one math fonts which can be quite different, right?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`\textrm` (and the corresponding switch `\rmfamily`) changes an aspect of the font – in this case the family. If possible other aspects – like the series (bold or not) or the shape (italic) – are preserved. `\text...`-commands can be nested and their "aspect changes" are combined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\sffamily\bfseries\itshape abc
\textrm{abc}\textrm{\textup{abc}}
\end{document}
```

[image: text]

`\mathrm` and the other math alphabets don't change only an aspect of a font. They switch to specific fonts. They make it possible to print symbols in special fonts. It is quite possible to setup things so that e.g. `\mathrm` use times, `\mathbf` is a bold palatino, `\mathit` a slanted Arial etc. You can also confuse everyone by defining `\mathbf` to be light itshape palatino and `\mathit` a bold Arial. You can define your own special math fonts e.g. `\mathvector` or `\mathmatrix` or `\mathfancy`. As all these commands switch to dedicated font they can't be nested. The last command (the inner one) always wins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

$\mathit{A}
 \mathbf{A}
 \mathit{\mathbf{A}}
 \mathbf{\mathit{A}}$

\end{document}
```

[image: math]

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for the necromancy, but, to go into a bit more detail:

The `\textrm` command uses the default font family, which is the one designated as `\familydefault` in NFSS or with `\setmainfont` if `fontspec` is loaded.  It also uses the weight and shape parameters of the surrounding text.  Therefore, the argument of `\textrm` will be italicized within an italic theorem statement or bold in a bold header.  The contents will be rendered in text mode, so spaces will appear in the output.

The `\mathrm` command uses the alphabet declared as `\mathrm`.  This is set with the `\DeclareMathAlphabet` or `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` command in NFSS, or the `\setmathrm` command in `fontspec`.  It will change the font to normal weight and upright shape, and the contents will be rendered in math mode, so spaces will be ignored.

Most font packages will set `\mathrm` and `\textrm` to the same font.  One exception is `eulerpx`, which sets the default Roman font to Palatino and the math alphabet to AMS Euler.