# Is \mathrm really preferable to \text?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, sans-serif

It seems to be the de facto standard to use `\mathrm` for upright letter notation in math mode as opposed to `\text`. Would it not be better to use `\text` in general?

One particular problem I am thinking of is when writing in a sans serif-style document (e.g. `beamer`). In many cases here, your text *and* math is set in a sans serif font (for screen readability, I guess). Using `\mathrm` in this case causes the argument to appear in a roman font (with serifs), whereas using `\text` seems to correctly pick up that the text style in the document is sans serif and display the argument in upright sans serif.

So, would it not be better to generally use `\text` instead of `\mathrm` for "upright" notation in math mode?

Comment: `\text{}` returns to the text mode and so it uses the current font. Also, try to type `\alpha+\text{A_1}+x`.

Comment: Both macros have their own purpose. `\mathrm` *still* contains mathematical symbols, whereas `\text` explicitly marks *text* and as such returns to text mode (which is different from math mode). In math mode you have different typesetting rules (e.g. spacing) and on top of that by using them interchangeably you don't make use of the semantic mark-up either. Bottomline: I strongly advise aginst this practice!

Comment: I never use `\mathrm`. Upright letters only appear in operators for me, so I use `\DeclareMathOperator`. Otherwise it is text, so I use `\text`.

Comment: My beamer uses sans-serif fonts for Latin letters inside math blocks.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer's solution seems to capture the best of both modes, so to speak. I suppose a good manual practice would then be to remember to use `\mathrm` when you are in a serif font "environment" and to use `\mathsf` when you are in a sans serif font "environment"?

Comment: @ThomasArildsen: You can also simply redefine `\mathrm` when you are in a sans serif environment (as far as I remember beamer e.g. does it). See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22350/difference-between-textrm-and-mathrm/22353#22353

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That is also an easy fix. However, at least in the beamer template I am trying here, `\mathrm` produces serif font. So I had better redefine to be on the safe side.

Comment: @mafp: Not only operators. The upright font must also be chosen in descriptive indices, such as in `$\rho_\textrm{Water}$`. Descriptive indices aren't variables, as opposed to, e. g., *i* in $x_i$ which is clearly a variable.

Comment: @AlexG: The only problem is that `\textrm` _won't_ always give you an upright font!

Comment: @AlexG: Isn't this actually a good example of where \text is appropriate, then?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Thanks for pointing this out. Would `\mathrm` be the better choice?

Comment: @ThomasArildsen: `\text` would use the document's main text font which may be Sans. I'd prefer the upright shape of the current math font.

Comment: @AlexG That would be text, as in $\rho_{\text{Water}}$. Still no use for `\mathrm`.

Comment: @mafp: You argued against **upright** font in general in equations (apart from operators).

Comment: @mafp: But `\rho_{\text{Water}}` won't give you upright `Water` in an italic context, so wouldn't `\mathrm` be the better choice? (Personally, I use the plain `\rm` ...)

Comment: @AlexG ...apart from operators *and text*. Your example is text, even when it is in a subscript.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Very good point! You should post an answer, as it is only very implicit in the other answers.

Comment: @mafp: `\text` is only appropriate for insertions that are **not** part of an equation (as amsldoc.pdf suggests), such as "if and only if" or "where", because you get the main text font (which is not what you want in the case of descriptive indices [and operators, of course]).

Comment: @AlexG But I *would* want it to be a textual item with the font of the surrounding text (modulo the limitation Hendrik pointed out), because it is a little piece of text. But I guess that is a matter of taste.

Comment: @mafp: I just don't know myself what would be "best practise" for things like `\rho_{\text{Water}}`.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I wouldn't use `\text` here, because  "Water" is part of the equation and should match the current math font (usually a serif font), not the surrounding text font which could be quite different. Textual insertions such as the ones mentioned in my comment above must of course use the surrounding text font and `\text` would be required for these.

Comment: @AlexG: Yeah, of course. But is `\mathrm` the best choice then? EDIT: Or maybe `\textnormal`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As has been said, `\text` is for text, and will change depending on the surrounding font. But math symbols in a document should always look the same: The meaning of a symbols also depends on the font used. So you should not use `\text` for mathematical symbols.

If you want an upright math font which adapts to the main document define it by using `\familydefault`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} %comment to see the difference
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathup}{OT1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

abc

$ a=\text{b}=\mathup{b}$

\itshape abc

$ a=\text{b}=\mathup{b}$


\sffamily abc

$ a=\text{b}=\mathup{b}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I guess I had misunderstood \text as more of a "\mathup" solution, but the above definitely seems better.

Comment: In [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22353/1053) to a similar topic you make mention of `\textrm`. Shouldn't this one be preferred over `\text` and `\mathrm` after all?

Comment: @AlexG: None of the commands "should be preferred": It depends on the context: As shown above `\text` e.g. adjust itself to the current text font (it also adjust size when used e.g. in superscripts. It uses the sans serif family in the last line. `\textrm` switches always to the roman family.

Answer (score 5):

How complicated does it become if we write the same equation with `\text` instead of `\mathrm`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\preview
$\int f(x)\, \mathrm{d_a}x$

$\int f(x)\, \text{d$_\text{a}$}x$
\endpreview
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: please ignore the mathematical aspect of the given expression above.

Comment: The shape of the `\text` version will change in a say a theorem environment where the surrounding text is italic.

Answer (score 4):

that depends to your problem. `\mathrm{...}` uses always Computer Modern and `\text{...}` the current text font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
%% instead of libertine use the following two lines:
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\Huge\sffamily
$\mathrm{Foo} \text{Foo}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the `libertine` package, I guess. I'm getting this warning `No file OT1fxl.fd. on input line 5.`

Comment: use another package eg `\usepackage{mathpazo}`

Comment: @Sigur You have an encoding problem. Your LaTeX found `libertine.sty`, that's why it is looking for `OT1fxl.fd`.

Comment: `\mathrm` will use the font that is set to be used as roman math font. It can be changed from Computer Modern!!

Comment: @rubenvb: That is obvious that it can be changed to another font.