# texts in equations not being showed properly using xepersian package

Tags: equations, text, xepersian, english

I'd like to insert an equation in my $LaTeX$ document that looks like the following equation but I fail to make it show the text inside the equation:

[image]

and the output I am getting:

[image]

I read questions\answers regarding the combination of Persian and English in xepersian and used \lr and latin but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{./styles/tempfix}
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{B Nazanin}
\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=2]{IranNastaliq}
\defpersianfont\titr[Scale=1]{B Titr}
\defpersianfont\traffic[Scale=1]{B Traffic}
\deflatinfont\calibri{Calibri}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P_J{:}\quad \min_{x} J(x) \quad \textrm{subject to} \quad y=Dx
%P_J{:}\quad \min_{x} J(x) \quad \lr\textrm{subject to} \quad y=Dx
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[There is a similar question which was closed.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199273/text-in-equation-in-xepersian)

Comment: Quick guess: maybe `\text{}` and `\mathrm{}` could be useful. See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22350/difference-between-textrm-and-mathrm).

Comment: Minimal example?

Comment: Oh \mathrm{} works, thank you for the quick guess @Karlo! :)

Comment: Not a minimal example: I get an error: `You have not specified any font for the main Persian text.`

Comment: @egreg oops, sorry! Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Your Persian font doesn't seem to support Latin character. If I use Scheherazade, it does:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\settextfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P_J{:}\quad \min_{x} J(x) \quad \textrm{subject to} \quad y=Dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P_J{:}\quad \min_{x} J(x) \quad \textnormal{\lr{subject to}} \quad y=Dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I really don't like to change the font.

Comment: @Gigili The alternative version doesn't require font changes; I used Scheherazade because that's the font I have.