# half space for Persian words in xepersian

Tags: spacing, xepersian, persian

I have windows 10 installed on my laptop and the system default Persian standard keyboard is also installed and used in text editors like notepad and MS Word. I have had no problem with typing half space since it is defined in the standard keyboard as `shift+space`.  In LaTeX (TeXLive and TeXworks) this shortcut key does not work and since half space is widely used (at least once in every sentence), I'm tired of the copy-paste trick where I type the word with half space in another editor and copy-paste it in LaTeX editor. Google search yield some other suggestions/shortcuts that don't work for me. (e.g. `ctrl + shift + 2`). What should I do about it? The font I am using for Persian text is what I had in the MWE in [my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325045/texts-in-equations-not-being-showed-properly-using-xepersian-package).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{./styles/tempfix}
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{B Nazanin}
\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=2]{IranNastaliq}
\defpersianfont\titr[Scale=1]{B Titr}
\defpersianfont\traffic[Scale=1]{B Traffic}
\deflatinfont\calibri{Calibri}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P_J{:}\quad \min_{x} J(x) \quad \textrm{subject to} \quad y=Dx
%P_J{:}\quad \min_{x} J(x) \quad \lr\textrm{subject to} \quad y=Dx
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Refer this link for more details on the spaces: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41488/75818.
You can also create macro in your editor for repeated usage.

Comment: In Linux, it simply works with `Shift + B` and in Windows, it works with `Shift + Space`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I installed a persian keyboard on my windows 10 and tried it out. "shift + space" inserted for me not a half-space but U+200C (ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER). ] I had no problem to insert and use with my normal latex editor (winedt) but it doesn't work in texworks.

Looking at the texworks bug tracker I found a related issue: https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/747.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the standard keyboard, no matter what editor or application you use, `shift+space` will produce half-space. However, there are some editors that have bugs (like the ones that use QT-5). You haven't mentioned the editor you are using (TexLive is a Latex distribution, not an editor). If you are using Tex Studio or TeXworks, you will find solutions on [here](http://qa.parsilatex.com/1683/%DA%86%D8%B7%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%AE%D9%87-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AC%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF-texstudio-%D9%86%DB%8C%D9%85-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%AF-%DA%A9%D9%86%D9%85%D8%9F), and [here](http://qa.parsilatex.com/2784/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D9%86%DB%8C%D9%85-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%AF%D8%B1-latex).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did mention the editor I use in the question body which is TeXworks, and also the forum I mentioned in my question is the one you linked to... Unfortunately the random shortcuts suggested there do not work for me.