# How can I have spaces in text within a formula?

Tags: spacing, pdftex

I have a series of TeX formulas where the author has put in spaces in the text, for example:

```
{\rm{Maximum credit}} = {{\mathop {{\rm{Net income from sources}}}\limits_{{\rm{without the United States}}} } \over {{\rm{Total net income}}}} \times \mathop {{\rm{United States tax on}}}\limits_{{\rm{total income}}}
```

Using [pdfTeX](http://tug.org/applications/pdftex/), this gets rendered without the spaces in the text:

[image]

What do I need to do to the TeX formula to get the spaces to show?

Comment: Try `\text{…}` instead of `\rm{…}`

Comment: You're probably interested in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWIjZ.png) representation, rather than the changing font sizes, correct?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `\rm` should never be used in latex, it has not been defined by default for almost 30 years, if you do use a class that defines it for compatibility with old documents then the syntax is `{\rm Maximum}` not `\rm{Maximum}`  but `\textrm{Maximum credit}` does what you want.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you use `\text` instructions for the 2 strings that don't need line breaking and `\parbox` directives for the 2 strings that do. Both `\text` and `\parbox` typeset their arguments in text mode, which is precisely what you want.

Remark: As @barbarabeeton has noted in a comment, if there's any chance at all that this type of "wordy equation" will occur in a setting that employs italics as the main font shape (such as the interior of a theorem-like environment), you should use `\textup` or `\textrm` instead of `\text` in order to assure that upright rather than italic characters are used.

For the following example code, I chose the widths of the `\parboxes` after a minimal amount of trial and error.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' macro
\begin{document}

\[
\text{Maximum credit} = 
\frac{\parbox{4cm}{\centering Net income from sources 
      without the United States\strut}}{%
      \text{Total net income}} 
\times 
\parbox{2.75cm}{\centering United States tax on total income}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Might want to specify `\textup` or `\textrm` instead of just plain `\text`.  If this happens to be located within a block of italic text (e.g., a theorem), just plain `\text` would follow the appearance of the environment.

Comment: Thanks, @barbarabeeton. I've added a paragraph to give the gist of your comment the visibility it deserves.

Answer (score 6):

- Load the `amsmath` package (or `mathtools` which also loads `amsmath`).
- The `amsmath` package offers the function `\text{}`.
- The `\text{}` function is intended to be used within math and respects spaces, e. g. `\text{Net income from sources}`.
- Alternatively, use `~` to create spaces, e. g. `\mathrm{without~the~United~States}`. Please be aware that I changed `\rm` to [`\mathrm`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22350) since this is the more appropriate command, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15361). See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353) for alternatives to `~`.

Comment: Since `\rm` is a switch and doesn't take an argument, you should probably write `{\rm without~the~United~States}`.

Comment: @mico thanks for the suggestion. I should have spent more time on the answer.

Comment: @Mico I have updated the answer and now use `\mathrm`, thanks again for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using LaTeX, be advised that `\rm` has been declared obsolete and deprecated about 30 years ago.

You should use instead `tabular` for the job, with which you don't need to guess the width of the material.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\wordvar}[1]{%
  \textup{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\wordvar{Maximum credit} =
\frac{\wordvar{Net income from sources \\ without the United States}}
     {\wordvar{Total net income}}
\times
\wordvar{United States tax on \\ total income}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're using plain TeX, it can be done in a similar way.

```
\def\wordvar#1{%
  \vcenter{\rm\ialign{\hfil\strut##\hfil\cr#1\crcr}}%
}

$$
\wordvar{Maximum credit} =
{
 \wordvar{Net income from sources \cr without the United States}
 \over
 \wordvar{Total net income}
}
\times
\wordvar{United States tax on \cr total income}
$$

\bye
```