# Hi, any one can tell me how to write long subscript in latex? example F_a_m_a_m

Tags: math-mode

Writing long subscript in latex example F_A_M_A_M

Comment: you need `\_` to make a `_` so `X_{\mathrm{F\_A\_M\_A\_M}}`

Comment: What does `F_A_M_A_M` mean? Do you just need to write a literal `_` to a document (→ `\_`)? Or do you want multiple characters set in subscript (→ `X_{\text{FAMAM}}`)?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `\text` is never a good idea for that.

Comment: @daleif Yeah, `\textrm` or `\mathrm` might be better depending on what it actually means.

Comment: I suggest `X\textsubscript{F\_A\_M\_A\_M}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I guess I'd better finish my overview article as to why peoples use of `\text` is often wrong.

Comment: @daleif [Q19502](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19502), [Q22350](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22350). I never use `theorem` environments or such things so I never have to deal with math content inside italic text. And I want my subscripts to inherit the sf when I'm using it in sf text.