# Italic Greek characters in Times New Roman

Tags: fonts, symbols, italic, greek

I'm very new to LaTeX!  I'm trying to create a template for creating scientific reports as PDFs.  I'd like the whole of the document to be in Times New Roman.  I've used the package `pslatex`, which works well except for the fact that none of the Greek characters (including those in equations) are italic as they should be.

Is there a way to make these characters italic?  The standard {`\it` ?} has no effect.  Or is there a package other than `pslatex` that puts the document in Times New Roman but doesn't cause this problem?

I'm using TeXShop.

This illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}            
\usepackage{pslatex}   %  This makes the font Times New Roman.
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,mathbbol}   % For maths symbols.

\usepackage{titlesec}                                       
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}                                                              
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,epsfig,ulem}
\usepackage[top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm, left=2.0cm, right=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}                   
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}             

\begin{document}

Times New Roman.

${\beta=3\alpha}$

{\it${\beta }$} = 3{\it${\alpha}$}

${\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon, \lambda, \phi, \rho, \varphi, \omega}$

\begin{equation}{\it t}_{1/2} = \dfrac{\ln(2)}{{\lambda}}.      
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding `\it` in general: Have a look at [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516)

Answer (score 4):

`pslatex` is really an obsolete package. You can use `mathptmx`, as already suggested, or

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

(which requires an updated TeX distribution).

### `mathptmx`

[image]

### `newtxtext` + `newtxmath`

[image]

Here is the source. Notice how the result is obtained more simply than you did (everybody must learn, when using a new tool).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}   % For maths symbols.

%%% uncomment one of the following and comment the other
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

Times New Roman.

$\beta=3\alpha$

$\beta=3\alpha$

$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon, \lambda, \phi, \rho, \varphi, \omega$

\begin{equation}
t_{1/2} = \frac{\ln(2)}{\lambda}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

(The difference in size is an artifact of the image production.)

Answer (score 2):

do not use the obsolete package `pslatex`. Use instead:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
```

and your greek letter should be in italic by default without `\it` which is already an old command, use `\textit` or `\itshape` instead.

Comment: Thanks!  Now if there are characters within math formatting which I don't want to be italic, how do I do that?  For example, with $^{137\text m}$Ba in my document, the m is now italicised, whereas before the \text command used to prevent that.

Comment: @Daniel [Is there a preference of when to use \text and \mathrm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19502) and [Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70632)

Comment: `$^{137\text{m}}$` Pay attention to the  parentheses. `$^{...}$` for more than one charcater as exponent. `$\text{m}$` for an upright m from the text char set

Comment: Thanks again.  The m was still typesetting as italic when I tried $^{137\text{m}}$ but $^{\mathrm{137m}}$Ba works the way I want it to.

Comment: then you have an \itshape or something else around there