# What is space in a math environment?

Tags: spacing, matrices

I want to get a space to the phrase `"1\times 8 \mathrm{ matrix}"`, how can I get it inside the math environment?

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
C_{D_{1\succ 2}, \mathrm{increasing}}   &=  \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1   &   -1  &   1   &   -1  &   1   &   -1  &   1   &   -1  \\ \end{pmatrix}}_{1\times 8\mathrm{ matrix}}       \\
A_{D_{1\succ 2}, \mathrm{increasing}}   &=  \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   \\
0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   &   0   &   1   \\
1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   \\
0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   \\
1   &   1   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\
1   &   1   &   1   &   1   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   0   \\
0   &   0   &   0   &   0   &   1   &   1   &   1   &   1   \\
\end{pmatrix}}_{7\times 8 \mathrm{ matrix}}.
\end{align*}
```

Comment: You can use `\textstyle` which at least uses the usual space between symbols. The phrase `matrix` is best typeset in text mode with `\text{ matrix}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel what is the difference between \mathrm and \text?

Comment: `\textstyle` uses, umm, the font defined by `\textrm`. In many settings `\mathrm` and `\textrm` will be mostly the same. A big difference arises in the treatment of space characters: They're ignored in math environments (since TeX has its own specialized rules for typesetting math material) but not in  text environments.

Comment: Also see [Is there a preference of when to use `\text` and `\mathrm`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19502/5764)

Comment: @hhh `\mathrm` is still math-mode, that means that spaces are not considered (as everywhere else in math-mode) and that `-` will be a minus sign. It looks like `matrix` is a word and therefore text. You should use `\text` here (or `\textrm` or `\textnormal` or …); see [Which command should I use for textual subscripts in math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98406) Do you also want the space around the `\times` to be as usual. The underbrace is set in `\scriptstyle` which doesn’t use horizontal space around binary symbols, similar to the subscripts in your formula (`\succ`/`,`).