# Failure of \text within theorem environment

Tags: amsmath, theorems

I have an equation within the statement of one of my theorems.  Within this equation, I have some text to name a function.  However, when this equation appears within the theorem environment, the output treats each letter of my function name as though it were a variable.  How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

$\text{Function}(x) = 1$

\begin{theorem}
$\text{Function}(x) = 1$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I just realized that `\mathrm` works fine.  But why is there a problem with `\text`?

Comment: This is the expected functionality since text within theorem environments is set in italics. The `\text` command from `amsmath` matches the local text font.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19503/21344

Comment: A better option, giving also better spacing, is to say `\DeclareMathOperator{\Func}{Function}` in the preamble and then `$\Func(x) = 1$`.

Comment: I agree with Gonzalo Medina. However if you want to stick to \text, you should use `\textup`. `\mathrm` will give you a letter spacing as though they were the variables F, u, n, c, &c.

Comment: @Bernard `\textup` acts only on the shape, so boldface would be preserved; unlikely, but possible.

Comment: @Egreg: You mean that one should write `\textup{\mdseries…}` if one doesn't want boldface?

Comment: @Bernard `\textnormal` is easier. However, for that case, `\operatorname{Function}` or Gonzalo's proposal is better.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina an answer?

Comment: @PaulGessler Answer added.

Answer (score 3):

`\text` honors the surrounding font. A better approach to get the desired font and the proper spacing is to use `\DeclareMathOperator`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Func}{Function}

\begin{document}

$\text{Function}(x) = 1\quad\Func(x) = 1$

\begin{theorem}
$\text{Function}(x) = 1\quad\Func(x) = 1$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]