# Awkward spacing in regression equation

Tags: spacing

My regression equation is not done yet, but the look of it is a but odd. Can someone help me with the spacing?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}


\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font

\begin{document}

OLS Regression is used to estimate the following equations:

${\textrm{CEO Salary}}={\beta}_0 +{\beta}_1 return$ +${\beta}_2 bonus$+${\beta}_2 stock awards$+${\beta}_2 option awards$+
\par${\beta}_2 other compensation$

\end{document}
```

[image]

@DavidCarlisle this is resulting in errors: what am I doing wrong?

```
{\textrm{CEO Salary}}={\beta}_0 +{\beta}_1 \mathrm{return} +{\beta}_2 \mathrm{bonus}+{\beta}_3 \mathrm{stock awards}+{\beta}_4 \mathrm{option awards}+
\par${\beta}_5 \mathrm{other compensation}+{\beta}_6 \mathrm{age}+{\beta}_7 \mathrm{age sq}+{\beta}_8 \mathrm{male}+{\beta}_9 \mathrm{industry}+{\beta}_10 Volume$
```

Comment: never use math italic for multi letter words it is designed to make adjacent letters look like a product of variables. use `\mathrm{return}` etc and don't do `$ +$` which is forcing the + _not_ to be part of the math expression,

Comment: How do I go past single digits for the betas? So like "Beta 10" is coming out as "Beta (sub 1) 0

Comment: the syntax for a subscript is `_{1234567}`  if you know what you are doing you can sometimes omit the braces without it going wrong but it is a bad idea to do that, even when it works.

Comment: @texmex this should be a different question but it's a simple one so I answer here and in a more general way. When you want to group more than one character/variable/digit you should encapsulate them in brackets (i.e. between `{` and `}`).

Comment: @texmex Since it seems to me that you are new to LaTeX, please take a look at [how to write math in LaTeX on Wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}


\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font

\begin{document}

OLS Regression is used to estimate the following equations:
$\text{CEO Salary} = 
  \beta_0 + 
  \beta_1\,\text{return} + 
  \beta_2\,\text{bonus} + 
  \beta_2\,\text{stock awards} + 
  \beta_2\,\text{option awards} +
  \beta_2\,\text{other compensation} $
\end{document}
```

[image: example_image]

**Some explanation**: In you example you typed multiple inline math, in my example there is only one. If you want to type some text just use `\text`. I used `\,` for two reasons:

- in my opinion is good to have a space (but not too much of it) between the variable and the word(s)
- `\,` is non-breakable, i.e. a new line cannot separate a variable from the word next to it.

**Further infos**: As David Carlisle pointed out in a comment, you can also use `\mathrm`. However `\mathrm` and `\text` are semantically different even if they can - but not in any case - have the same result. You should use `\mathrm` when you have math variables that you don't want to display in mathmode (i.e. italic) and you should use `\text` when you have... text. For further differences please look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/is-there-a-preference-of-when-to-use-text-and-mathrm).