# Splitting equations using \begin{split} generates errors (again)

Tags: equations, split

I have been successfully using "split" to split up long equation, but now I get a new error:

```
 \begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
    \alpha_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F(y)\text{d}y=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{d}y+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\text{d}y+\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{d}y+\frac{3}{\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\text{d}t\\ \alpha_0=\frac{5}{2}+\frac{3(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}){\pi}
     \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

gives a lot of errors

I have tried many version, but can't get that $\alpha_0=\frac{5}{2}+\frac{3(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}){\pi}$ to start at the second line, to the left...

Any ideas welcomed!

Thanks

Comment: I can't find the `\begin{split}` in your example... (and to split you use `\\\`, `&` is for `align`)

Comment: See update.....

Comment: You have a runaway argument. Check it (writing the formula on different input lines, with logical spacing and indeneting, will help a lot).

Comment: `\frac{3(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}){\pi}` is missing a closing brace for the outer fraction's numerator

Comment: Unrelated, don't use `\text` like that. That is not what `\text` is for and in certain cases it will produce the wrong result. Use `\mathrm{d}` etc insted.

Comment: Thanks Dai!  ...

Comment: Once you add the missing `}` and add a `&` in front of both the `=` signs, your code compiles just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\frac{3(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}){\pi}` is giving an unmatched brace (this is presumably the [first error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125404/106162) you are seeing, and once resolved should fix the subsequent errors) and should probably be `\frac{3(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2})}{\pi}`.

Preferring `\mathrm{d}` ([Is there a preference of when to use \text and \mathrm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19502/106162)), then you simply need to set an alignment point on the first equals sign

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
   \alpha_0 &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F(y)\mathrm{d}y=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}y+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\mathrm{d}y+\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{d}y+\frac{3}{\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\mathrm{d}t\\ 
   \alpha_0 &= \frac{5}{2}+\frac{3(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2})}{\pi}
  \end{split}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Compiling using `aligned` enviroment you get the same result.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
   \alpha_0 &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F(y)dy=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}dy+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}dy+\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}dy+\frac{3}{\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}dt\\ 
   \alpha_0 &= \frac{5}{2}+\frac{3(\pi-\frac{\pi}{2})}{\pi}
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]